# Loop isn't working

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that reads the user's input. If the user inputs a wrong choice, the program goes into loop mode until the user chooses not to make another choice.

Here's my desired output:

```
    choose (1): To find if the student fulfil the words count criteria 
    choose (2): To find if all sentences start with a Capital letter 
    choose (3): To find how many of the keywords used 
    choose (4): To find a word in the essay
    choose (5): To replace a word in the essay
    choose (6): To score the essay and print a report
    choose (7): To Exit

    Please Enter your choice: 1
You chose 1
        Do you want to choose another option (yes/no): 
Yes


    choose (1): To find if the student fulfil the words count criteria 
    choose (2): To find if all sentences start with a Capital letter 
    choose (3): To find how many of the keywords used 
    choose (4): To find a word in the essay
    choose (5): To replace a word in the essay
    choose (6): To score the essay and print a report
    choose (7): To Exit

    Please Enter your choice:
```

My problem is: the program exits before it asks the user if they want to choose another option

Here’s my output:

```
    choose (1): To find if the student fulfil the words count criteria 
    choose (2): To find if all sentences start with a Capital letter 
    choose (3): To find how many of the keywords used 
    choose (4): To find a word in the essay
    choose (5): To replace a word in the essay
    choose (6): To score the essay and print a report
    choose (7): To Exit

    Please Enter your choice: 1
You chose 1
        Do you want to choose another option (yes/no): BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Here's my code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
      boolean checkflag = false;
      String answer;
      int choice;
   do {checkflag=false;

        System.out.println("\n\n\n");
                   System.out.print("       choose (1): To find if the student fulfil the words count criteria \n"
                + "     choose (2): To find if all sentences start with a Capital letter \n"
                + "     choose (3): To find how many of the keywords used \n"
                + "     choose (4): To find a word in the essay\n"
                + "     choose (5): To replace a word in the essay\n"
                + "     choose (6): To score the essay and print a report\n"
                + "     choose (7): To Exit\n"
                + "\n       Please Enter your choice: ");

        choice = input.nextInt();

        if ((choice == 1)||(choice == 2)||(choice == 3)||(choice == 4)||(choice == 5)||(choice == 6)) {
            System.out.println("You chose " + choice);
        }

        else  if (choice == 7) {
            System.exit(0);
        } 


        else {
            System.out.print("        Incorrect entry, Please try again with valid entry from the list."
                    + "\n                 Please Enter your choice: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.print("      Do you want to choose another option (yes/no): ");

        answer = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n\n\n");
    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code.

Comment: It might be better to not ask and let the user enter 7 if they don't want to enter any more commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

`answer = input.nextLine();`

to

`answer = input.next();`

[`nextLine` advances the scanner to the next line and gives the input that was skipped (Javadoc [here][1]) whereas `next()` waits for the next input and returns it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

Answer (score 0):

public static void sentencesChecker(String essay) {

```
    int count = 1;


    int countcap=0;

    String sent = ".";

    String senten;

    for (int i = 0; i < essay.length() - 1; i++) {

        if (essay.charAt(i) == '.') {
            count++;
        }

        if ((essay.charAt(i)) >= 'A' || (essay.charAt(i)) <= 'Z') {
            countcap++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code is to find how many sentences start with a Capital letter but it's doesn't work . what is the problem ?

Comment: @Ole V.V. here :(